# How to use concepts with gcc 6

Tags: c++, gcc, c++-concepts

I am trying to write a class that should require the concept [Container](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Container) with [gcc 6](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C_002b_002b-Concepts.html).

What I tried is:

```
class MyContainer { ... };
static_assert(std::Container<MyContainer>);
```

But I can't manage to make it compile.

Comment: Hello, that(your comment and the duplicate topic) does not answer my question, how to make my program compiles? what is the correct syntax?

Comment: So... where does `std::Container` come from?

Comment: You should read the first few paragraphs of your link; they explain that the "concepts" listed there are only for explaining how that type of object should behave and does not define tangible objects or language constructs. You may be confusing it with the Concepts TS explained here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints

Comment: @Nicol I wanted to use the Container concept (look at the link)

Comment: By the way, why did I have a negative score? Is my question not clear? Thanks

Comment: "can't manage to make it compile" is *not* something a question with positive score might say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concepts TS does not come with any actual concepts in it. It's just the language feature. The "concepts" used by the C++ standard are *not implemented* by Concepts TS.

So this `std::Container` you're trying to access doesn't exist. You can read the requirements the standard uses and *create* one.